# Puedo formar un WHERE en una variable de @?

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

Una pregunta,
Puedo meter en una variable la condición (WHERE) ?? donde contenga todas las condiciones y usarlo al final de mi SP? si es que se puede, como podría hacerlo?

algo asi como

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE fecha = @condiciones;
```

Donde @condiciones contega algo como:

```
 @condiciones = '2018-08-08' AND condicion2 = 'www' AND condicion3 = 'wwwwww';
```

Comment: si no mal entendí tu pregunta, mi respuesta es si. cada variable debes declararla junto a su sentencia. o a su comando. solo crea el sp y intentalo.

Comment: en definitiva si estas declarando un parametro - `(@parametro)` -, es todo lo que necesitas amigo.. el valor de dicho parametro será el encargado de filtrar según lo que le solicites al sp

Comment: creo que no quedo clara la pregunta, yo lo que quiero es que en la variable (@condiciones) guardarle mas de una condición. Para que al momento de hacer el WHERE solo tenga que usar una, en este caso (@condiciones)

Comment: Mmmm.. yo creo que quieres implementar algo demasiado "creativo", ya que por ejemplo imagino que a esa `@condiciones` quieres asignarle valores de fecha, texto, números, bit, etc... Imagino que quieres hacer eso para ahorrar espacio en memoria y todo lo que implica, pero no sé realmente si se podrá... creo que sería algo como un `Enum` en programación lo que quieres, pero como te dije, ignoro si es posible hacerlo.. sólo conozco la forma "común" (un parámetro por condición)

Comment: Yo lo veo más como querer pasar como parámetro un fragmento de consulta y concatenarlo al texto de la query incluida en el sp. Será esa la idea?

Answer (score 3):

Si, pero conceptualmente es algo totalmente distinto. Antes que nada, cuando haces:

```
SELECT * FROM Tabla WHERE Columna = @Valor
```

No es más que una consulta normal, parametrizada. El motor la toma, la compila y puede, si así lo determina, hacer un plan de ejecución que optimice la consulta para minimizar los recursos del servidor y paralelamente mejorar la performance.

Lo que buscas se puede hacer sin duda, pero mediante algo que se conoce como [consultas dinámicas](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/).  Es decir sentencias que creas dinámicamente. La forma más simple, podría ser algo así:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT * 
                      FROM TABLA 
                      WHERE COLUMNA_VARCHAR=''VALOR'' 
                      AND COLUMNA_NUMERICA=1'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Observaciones:

- No puedes combinar una sentencia tradicional con una dinámica son cosas distintas
- la sentencias la escribes encerrada por comillas tal cual la escribirías  normalmente pero debes escapar las comillas internas con dobles comillas
- Este tipo de consultas no puede ser optimizada por el motor, lo que mencionabamos al principio
- Si queremos parametrizar la consulta, una forma es concatenar los valores de cada parámetro mediante una variable, por ejemplo `.. COLUMNA_VARCHAR = ''' + @Valor + '''....'`, pero **NO** es la forma adecuada ya que esto es suceptible de [**Inyección SQL**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL). La forma correcta es el uso de [`sp_execute_sql`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) y la parametrización de cada parámetro.

Answer (score 1):

Claro que puedes, esta sería una manera de hacerla:

`Declare @condiciones varchar(max)= 'WHERE campo1 = valor1 AND campo2 = valor2'`

Y para ejecutar la consulta, harías lo siguiente:

```
EXEC('SELECT * FROM TABLA' +@condiciones)
```

Lo anterior equivaldría a ejecutar directamente:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE campo1 = valor1 AND campo2 = valor2
```

Comment: y como se almacenaria el select y se recorreria?

Comment: Hola, no entendí bien tu pregunta.

Comment: la verdad darle un plus a tu respuesta, como por ejemplo realizar una iteracion  al ejecutar la funcion `(exec())` podria ser muy iutil para otros

Comment: Sumado a que esa variable @condiciones sólo esta guardando **textualmente** el `WHERE`

Comment: La variable puede almacenar una consulta de manera parcial o total segun la necesidad. El poder que tienen este tipo de consultas es que tu puedes realizar consultas dinamicas, de tal manera que segun el flujo de tu programa puedes ir armando el query segun los filtros y valores que se vayan requiriendo.

Comment: como comentas @BytesMan quiero ir armando el query dependiendo los  el flujo del programa e ir concatenandole datos al where para armar toda el filtro